# If I pre-purchase D3 RoS Deluxe Edition will I receive the bonus content for other Blizzard games before it's release?

Tags: diablo-iii

I want to pre-purchase Diablo 3 Reaper of Souls Deluxe Edition, but I want to know if I'll receive Wow and SC2's content now.

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will not be available immediately, but you may receive them before the game is released.

> **What is included in the Digital Deluxe edition?**
>
> The Digital Deluxe version of includes a digital copy of the expansion along with the following exclusive in-game bonus items for StarCraft II, World of Warcraft, and Hearthstone:
>
> - A summonable skeletal minion.
> - 3 additional Diablo III character slots.
> - 3 Hearthstone booster packs.
> - A set of Diablo portraits for your StarCraft II account.
> - A set of Diablo decals for your StarCraft II buildings.
> - A Treasure Goblin pet for your World of Warcraft account.
> - 7 Malthael-themed no-stat weapons, suitable for transmogrification.
> - 3 no-stat helmets suitable for transmogrification.
>
> **Note: In-game bonus items will not be available immediately, and may be distributed separately.**

https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-reaper-of-souls-presale-faq

Comment: If I read this answer and the FAQ correct, only the items on that list specifically saying they're for WoW or StarCraft II is not for Diablo 3 RoS, the rest of the items are for RoS. Is that correct? Meaning I won't get the 10 items for transmogrification in WoW, say?